# Odd cycle transversal

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

Suppose we have a graph **G**. Say **B** a fundamental basis of the cycle space of **G**. Say *LP* a linear programming problem where there is a variable for each vertex of **G**, each variable can take value $\geq 0$, for each odd cycle of **B** we add to *LP* the constraint $x_{a} + x_{b} + x_{c} + ... + x_{i} \geq k$ where $x_{a},x_{b},x_{c},...,x_{i}$ are the verteces of the cycle and $k$ is the number of vertices of the cycle. The objective function of *LP* is $\min\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}}$.

We say **S** an optimal solution of *LP*. Can we say that each vertex, whose variable takes a value $\gt 0$ in **S**, is a vertex of at least a minimum [odd cycle transversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_cycle_transversal) of **G**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**  Let $G$ be the graph obtained by gluing a $3$-cycle $abc$ and a $5$-cycle $cdefg$ together at vertex $c$.  Then $(x_a, x_b, x_c, x_d, x_e, x_f, x_g)=(0,0,3,1,1,0,0)$ is an optimal solution of the LP.  However, neither $d$ nor $e$ are contained in a minimum odd cycle transversal of $G$, since $\{c\}$ is the unique minimum odd cycle transversal of $G$.

The answer is also **no** to the updated question in the comment below.  Here is a counterexample for both versions.  Let $C_n$ be an odd cycle with $n \geq 5$.  Fix $e=ab \in E(C_n)$ and let $T=C_n - e$.  Let $G$ be the graph obtained from $C_n$ by adding all edges $f$ such that $T \cup f$ contains an even cycle.  Then, the fundamental basis of $G$ with respect to $T$ contains exactly one odd cycle, namely $C_n$.  Thus, $x=(\frac{1}{n}, \dots, \frac{1}{n})$ is an optimal solution to the revised LP (see comment below) and $x=(1, \dots, 1)$ is an optimal solution to the original LP.  However, it is not true that every vertex of $G$ is in a minimum odd cycle transversal, because the only minimum odd cycle transversals of $G$ are $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. Then I would like to change the question just a little bit: what about if we replace the constraint *x_a+x_b+x_c+...+x_i >= k* with *x_a+x_b+x_c+...+x_i >= 1* for each odd cycle of **B**?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your counterexample: if we suppose *n* = 5, **C**_*n* is the odd cycle with edges *ab*, *bc*, *cd*, *de*, *ea*. **T** is the graph with edges *bc*, *cd*, *de*, *ea*. **G** is the graph with edges *ab*, *ad*, *bc*, *bd*, *cd*, *ce*, *de*, *ea*. **G** has 5 odd cycles: *abcde*, *abd*, *bcd*, *cde*, *dea*. Now it is not true that *a* is an odd cycle transversal of **G**, because if we remove the vertex *a*, the odd cycle *cde* is still alive (the same if we remove the vertex *b*). I am sorry if I have misunderstood your counterexample.

Comment: You are supposed to add the edges $be$ and $ac$ (not $ce, bd$, and $ad$) to $C_5$.

Comment: Ok, I think that if we add the constraint $x_{a} + x_{b} + x_{c} + ... + x_{i} \geq 1$ for each odd cycle of **G** (not only for the odd cycles of **B**), then we can say that each vertex, whose variable take a value $\gt  0$ in an optimal solution of *LP*, is a vertex of at least a minimum odd cycle transversal of **G**. Is it right?